# сортировка списка словарей по значению ключа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Объясните пожалуйста работу этого кода, если можно подробно.
Находил на форуме подобный вопрос, но без объяснения.(Находил много решений с lambda но там вообще ни черта не понятно. Лямбды отбросил в сторону на долго, пока хорошо не усвоится весь материал.)
Не судите строго - я новичок.

Вот почему функция mykey() вызывается без скобок?
Что вообще происходит в этой функции?

Если функция возвращает строку 'age', то почему нельзя просто написать key = 'age'? Почему это вызовет ошибку? Читал Byte of Python и там практически все понятно на 99% кроме этого момента который там решается через лямбду.

Почему все функции вызываются со скобками? Почему вызов функций без скобок всегда (кроме данного случая) вызывает ошибку, а тут наоборот?
Все шло отлично, пока не напоролся на это №@%№
Что такое объект функции? Какая разница между foo() и просто foo ? Эти моменты мне не понятны и пока не нашел понятного объяснения. В этой книге этого тоже нет :-(

```
x = [{'name' : 'Homer', 'age' : 39}, {'name' : 'Bart', 'age' : 100}]

def mykey(a):
    return a['age'] 

print(sorted(x, key = mykey))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если функция возвращает строку 'age', то почему нельзя просто написать key = 'age'?

Причина этого в том, что функция `sorted` это библиотечная функция, которая предназанчена для сортировки любых объектов. Ну то есть авторы стандартной библиотеки когда ее писали, то сделали так, чтоб можно было ее использовать для списка любых объектов.

Если подумать, то для функции сортировки объектов всего-то нужно знать сам список и способ, как сравнить два объекта, чтобы для абсолютно любых двух объектов можно было сказать какой из них больше, а какой меньше.

Допустим вы написали функцию сортировки для обычных чисел и она отлично работает, быстро, все довольны. А теперь вам нужно сортировать словари. Сам алгоритм сортировки не меняется от того, что поменялись объекты. Единственное что в нем меняется, это то как в алгоритме сравниваются элементы списка.

Вы можете спросить "ок, я ведь передаю словарь, почему просто не дать возможность указать ключ из словаря по которому сортировать?"

И опять причина в универсальности. А если вы захотите отсортировать не просто по `age`, а сначала по `age`, а если возраст одинаковый, то вы хотите, чтоб такие словари шли в алфавитном порядке по `name`? В этом случае передача просто имени ключа не сработает, нужно передавать список. А если вы захотите сортировать по возрасту в убывающем порядке, а потом по имени в возрастающем? Теперь для каждого имени поля нужно передавать еще и направление сортировки.

Это можно в принципе сделать. И авторы библиотеки могли пойти (но не пошли этим путем, а выбрали более универсальный и элегантный способ). Тогда бы вызов функции выглядел так:

```
print(sorted(x, keys_to_sort_by = [('age', 'desc'), ('name', 'asc)]))
```

тут мы передаем список пар `(имя-поля, направление-сортировки)` (`asc` - по возрастанию, `desc` - по убыванию).

Но в этом подходе есть проблемы:

1. что делать, если у нас одно из полей дата и нужно сортировать по месяцу? Т.е. если значение поля напрямую не годится, а нам нужно из значения извлечь (или по другому, на основании значения посчитать) другое значение. Как в этом примере нам из даты нужно получить месяц и его использовать для сортировки. Или аналогичный пример, если нужно отсортировать так, чтоб сначала шли дети до 18 лет по алфавиту, а потом взрослые тоже по алфавиту (в этом случае мы используя поле возраст должны посчитать признак "ребенок/взрослый" и по нему сортировать в первую очередь, считая что "ребенок" < "взрослый").
2. это будет работать только для словарей. Для других типов объектов придется писать другу функцию. Авторы библиотеки же хотят написать универсальную функцию, которую бы можно было использовать для любых типов.

Чтоб решить эти проблемы используется такой трюк: вместо сравнения самих элементов, сравниваются рассчитанные для элементов значения. И для получения такого значения (которое называется ключом сортировки - потому и параметра называется `key`, не путать с ключом в словаре!) используется функция, которую пользователь `sorted` передает в параметре. Т.е внутри алгоритма сортировки в месте где раньше (для алгоритма с числами) делалось сравнение:

```
def sorted(elements):
    ....
    if el1 =< el2:
      # el1 должен быть раньше el2 в результате, продолжаем с учетом этого
    else:
      # el2 должен быть раньше el1 в результате, продолжаем с учетом этого
```

будет так:

```
def sorted(elements, key):
    ....
    if key(el1) =< key(el2):
      # el1 должен быть раньше el2 в результате, продолжаем с учетом этого
    else:
      # el2 должен быть раньше el1 в результате, продолжаем с учетом этого
```

Как видите для элемента из последовательности, которую мы сортирует, вызываем функцию (обратите внимание, используем скобки `key(el1)` - это означает "вызвать функцию, которая хранится в переменной key и передать ей параметром значение из переменной el1"), которую передали в параметре `key`, и в нее передаем сам элемент. И значит функция сможет "достать" из элемента значение, которое уже будет использоваться в сравнении.

Это очень гибкий способ, так как он позволяет сравнивать любые элементы причем в зависимости от ситуации (как нам может понадобиться по разному в разных случаях сортировать тот же список словарей, или менять порядок сортировки чисел или строк).

Например, если нужно сортировать числа по убыванию то используем функцию:

```
def in_reverse(num):
   return -num
```

Если хотим задать сортировку списка словарей сначала по возрасту потому по имени, то подойдет такая функция:

```
def by_age_then_name(el):
   return (el['age'], el['name])
```

Тут ключевая функция возвращает кортеж (tuple), и сравниваться будут кортежи, а у них как известно, сравнение работает так, что меньшим будет тот, у которого первый компонент меньше (и тут мы туда положили возраст) или, если первые компоненты одинаковы, то сравниваются вторые. В итоге, получаем то, что нам нужно.

> Какая разница между foo() и просто foo

Вот аналогия. В объявлении о продаже товара можно сказать "цена на товар $100". А можно написать "цену на товар можно узнать по телефону". Во втором случае пользователь объявления должен позвонить по телефону чтоб узнать цену (т.е. вызвать функцию, чтоб получить значение). Мы ему передали только возможность получить значение позже (т.е. саму функцию `foo`, а не значение, которое она вычисляет).

Comment: Преогромнейшая благодарность и низкий поклон!

Comment: (которое называется ключом сортировки - потому и параметра называется key, не путать с ключом в словаре!) вот оно что! начало немного проясняться. Да и подсказки при написании кода часто далеко не понятные.

Answer (score 2):

Много вопросов получается, но отвечу по мере сил.

> Вот почему функция mykey() вызывается без скобок?

Все дело в функции sorted, которая в качестве параметра key принимает функцию, как написано в руководстве:
Итерируемый объект можно также отсортировать по функции, указанной в параметре key. Это может быть:

```
Встроенная функция,
Определенная пользователем функция,
Лямбда-функция,
itemgetter,
attrgetter.
```

[Ссылка с описанием sorted](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/vozmozhnosti-i-primery-funkcii-sorted-v-python)

> Что вообще происходит в этой функции?

Функция возвращает значение age, но оно не будет работать напрямую, если вы например напишете

```
print(mykey(x))
```

т.к. он на вход должен получать их по одному, что-то типо такого:

```
print(mykey(x[0]))
```

> Если функция возвращает строку 'age', то почему нельзя просто написать
> key = 'age'? Почему это вызовет ошибку?

Ответ дал чуть выше, потому что в качестве параметров должна быть функция.

Надеюсь что-то смог объяснить.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо за разъяснение!!!

Comment: А можно эту функцию как-то переписать, чтобы было более понятно?

Answer (score 2):

> Если функция возвращает строку 'age', то почему нельзя просто написать key = 'age'? Почему это вызовет ошибку?

Функция не возвращает строку `'age'`, а получает на вход словарь, и возвращает то что в этом словаре записано по ключу `'age'`.

Пример:

```
def mykey(a):
    return a['age']

d = {'name' : 'Homer', 'age' : 39}
print(mykey(d))  # Выведет 39
```

> Вот почему функция mykey() вызывается без скобок?

Без скобок — потому что данная функция напрямую не вызывается, а как объект передается внутрь функции `sorted`, а внутри уже вызывается для каждого из сортируемых элементов, потом полученное значение используется как ключ сортировки (значение, по которому объекты сортируются). В данном случае из каждого элемента списка извлекается возраст, потом по возрасту происходит сортировка.

> Что такое объект функции? Какая разница между foo() и просто foo ?

Ну если как очень дальнюю аналогию можно представить, что объект функции — это как автобус, который стоит на стоянке, и никуда не едет. Вызов функции (со скобками) — это в автобус загрузили людей (параметры функции), он поехал, привез людей куда-то — функция выполнилась, получился какой-то результат.

Передача функции без скобок в другую функцию — вы продали автобус какой-то фирме, которая собирается на нем возить людей. Сами вы при этом этот автобус не отправляете в рейс, только "продали" его какой-то фирме.

Почему такой код не будет работать:

```
print(sorted(x, key = mykey(x[0])))
```

Потому что тут мы сами отправили "автобус" в рейс, а "продать" пытаемся результат этой отправки, а не сам "автобус".

> Читал Byte of Python и там практически все понятно на 99% кроме этого момента который там решается через лямбду.

Лямбда — это просто безымянная функция. Можно лямбду записать в переменную, и она будет работать как обычная функция, т.е.:

```
mykey = lambda a: a['age']

# это по сути то же самое, что 

def mykey(a):
    return a['age']
```

> Почему вызов функций без скобок всегда (кроме данного случая) вызывает ошибку

Это не вызовет ошибку, просто "автобус" никуда не поедет :)

Поедет только если вы сами отправите в рейс (вызовете функцию со скобками), или если это сделает кто-то другой (вы передадите функцию куда-то, где эта функция будет вызвана со скобками).

Comment: С автобусом прикольно ))  Ну и в целом хорошо расписано всё

Comment: @insolor "Функция не возвращает строку 'age', а получает на вход словарь, и возвращает то что в этом словаре записано по ключу 'age'." где это видно? 
Нигде же не указано, что в переменную а попадает что-то. только возвращается. Если честно, то не въехал. Тупой я, как автобус. Уже и дополнительно перечитал кучу объяснений и не погял.
можно переписать код, чтобы понятней было? Походу программирование это не мое.

Comment: @ВадимСоловьев, подразумевается, что функция sorted через параметр key получает функцию с одним параметром, которую она сама будет вызывать и передавать в нее значения из сортируемого списка. Где это видно - в документации к функции [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted): `key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in iterable`

Comment: @insolor Вы где-то учились? Не подскажете где такому учат? я проходил курсы на stepik, читал Майкл Доусон - Программируем на Python, Гэддис Т. - Начинаем программировать на Python - 2019 но такому нигде не учат. Вот как самому научиться решать подобные проблемы? Куда копать в подобных сиитуациях. Ведь не всегда получается обратиться к таким замечательным людям, да и голову вам морочить постоянно не хватает наглости. Тем более если не научиться решать самому, то ничему не научишься.

Comment: @ВадимСоловьев, ну, я довольно давно начинал. Концепцию передачи функции в другую функцию впервые узнал из языка Си, лет 15 назад, но там конкретно декларируется какой тип функции ожидается. Ну а при переходе на Python эта концепция была уже понятна.