# почему не выдает ошибку код?

Tags: python

я не понимаю что за переменная i после объявления lambda и на что она ссылается? Почему же скрипт не выдает ошибку?

```
points = [{ 'x' : 2, 'y' : 3 }, { 'x' : 4, 'y' : 1 }]
points.sort(key=lambda i : i['y'])
print(points)
```

Comment: i - это параметр лямбды в данном случае. По сути параметр функции.

Comment: Почитайте еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1338196/218971